# How to add where clause to Laravels Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to add conditions to my search with Query Builder. So if the access is 1 add this 'where', else the other 'where'. But the thing is that to do this I have to repeat the same code and change just the where. I am doing this:

```
if(access==1){
    $search = DB::table('users')
                       ->select('name')
                       ->where('case',$x)
                       ->get();
 } else {
      $search = DB::table('users')
                       ->select('name')
                       ->where('case',$y)
                       ->get();
}
```

I just wanna do something like this

```
search = DB::table('users')
                   ->select('name');
if(access==1){
        $search->where('case',$x);
     } else {
          $search->where('case',$y);
    }

$search->get()
```

I've simplified my example but here I have else of as well. So probably there's a way to do what I want, but I don't know how.

Comment: You should use `==` instead of `=` in the condition. Then it would be  fine. But You could also do somthing like `where('case', access==1 ? $x, $y)`. I would thoug use your second example.

Comment: @Daniel please don't modify your question based on input from other users, as this invalidates what they say and in some cases is the cause of the problem. In this case, it really seems that your code will work without the typos, please leave your question in the "answerable" (or in this case, off-topic) state in which it was created.

Comment: I wrote the code with my cellphone so I didn't realized the error with = instead of ==. Now everything is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign result to `$search` variable and replace `=` by `==` in condition if your real code is more difficult of course:

```
$search = DB::table('users')->select('name');

if($access == 1)
     {
        $search = $search->where('case',$x);
     } 
     else 
     {
        $search = $search->where('case',$y);
     }

$search = $search->get()
```

Comment: That's it. This solved my problem. The thing is that get() returns the result but I must use one variable to get it, and I wasn't. Thanks a loot

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two cases, you can simply use:

```
$search = DB::table('users')
    ->select('name')
    ->where('case', (($access == 1)?$x:$y)))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is the right idea (although it has a bunch of typos, e.g. using `=` instead of `==`).

As another alternative, Laravel also supports built-in [conditional where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses) that look something like this:

```
$search = DB::table('users')->select('name')
    ->when($access === 1, function($q) use ($x) {
        return $q->where('case', $x);
    })
    ->when($access === 2, function($q) use ($y) {
        return $q->where('case', $y);
    })
    ->get();
```